# removing all spaces within a specific string (email address) using ruby

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

The user is able to input text, but the way I ingest the data it often contains unnecessary carriage returns and spaces.

To remove those to make the input look more like a real sentence, I use the following:

```
string.delete!("\n")
string = string.squeeze(" ").gsub(/([.?!]) */,'\1  ')
```

But in the case of the following, I get an unintended space in the email:

```
string = "Hey     what is \n\n\n up joeblow@dude.com      \n okay"
```

I get the following:

```
"Hey what is up joeblow@dude.  com okay"
```

How can I enable an exception for the email part of the string so I get the following:

```
"Hey what is up joeblow@dude.com okay"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited**

your method does the following:

```
 string.squeeze(" ") # replaces each squence of " " by one space
 gsub(/([.?!] */, '\1 ') # check if there is a space after every char in the between the brackets [.?!]
                         # and whether it finds one or more or none at all
                         # it adds another space, this is why the email address
                         # is splitted
```

I guess what you really want by this is, if there is no space after punctuation marks, add one space. You can do this instead.

```
string.gsub(/([.?!])\W/, '\1 ') # if there is a non word char after 
                                # those punctuation chars, just add a space
```

Then you just need to replace every sequence of space chars with one space. so the last solution will be:

```
string.gsub(/([.?!])(?=\W)/, '\1 ').gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
# ([.?!]) => this will match the ., ?, or !. and capture it
# (?=\W) => this will match any non word char but will not capture it.
# so /([.?!])(?=\W)/ will find punctuation between parenthesis that
# are followed by a non word char (a space or new line, or even 
# puctuation for example).
# '\1 ' => \1 is for the captured group (i.e. string that match the 
# group ([.?!]) which is a single char in this case.), so it will add 
# a space after the matched group.
```

Comment: So if there were a lot of spaces after a ? Or . It would just be one space. And if there were no spaces it wouldn't do anything?

Comment: just to make sure --- I do *not* want to add a space and split the email address....both the second and the last one would support that right?  It seems like the second one would still add a space, though.

Comment: So the answer is the secod line of code, the first line of code is the old code and I just remove it, right?

Comment: @Angela yes the solution is the last one. It is what you need.

Comment: okay I think I see now...but if it replaces with a space, won't it add a space in `email.com`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with getting rid of the squeeze statement then, using Nafaa's answer is the simplest way to do it but I've listed an alternate method in case its helpful:

```
string = string.split(" ").join(" ")
```

However, if you want to keep that squeeze statement you can amend Nafaa's method and use it after the squeeze statement:

```
string.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').gsub('. com', '.com')
```

or just directly change the string:

```
string.gsub('.  com', '.com')
```

Comment: My solution should be applied on the original string. not after it process it with here code `string.squeeze(" ").gsub(/([.?!]) */,'\1  ')`.

Comment: So in that case remove the squeeze statement?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @NafaaBoutefer, I've amended my answer.

Comment: @Angela, yes you would remove the squeeze statement using Nafaa's answer or my alternative but I have added another gsub to use if you want to keep the squeeze statement.

Comment: I added the `gsub` above, now I have a space after every `.` in a .com.... so will the `string = string.split(" ").join(" ")` solve that?